Proof of a corollary of Pythagoras's theorem in a prehilbert space

Theorem.
Let $X$ be a prehilbert space and let $\{x_1,...,x_n\}\subseteq X$ (where $n\geq 2$) be an orthonormal finite subset. Taken $x\in X$, then we have that:
$$\|x\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n|\langle x,x_i\rangle|^2+\left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,x_i\rangle x_i\right\|^2$$

My attempt to prove it is the following.
Proof.
For a previous theorem, the set $$\left\{\Bigl\{\langle x,x_i\rangle x_i\Bigl\}_{i=1}^n \cup \space\Bigl\{x-\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,x_i\rangle x_i\Bigl\}\right\}$$ is orthogonal.
Then, for Pythagoras's theorem, I have that:
$$\|x\|^2=\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,x_i\rangle x_i+\left(x-\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,x_i\rangle x_i\right)\right\|^2=\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,x_i\rangle x_i\right\|^2+\space\left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,x_i\rangle x_i\right\|^2=$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n|\langle x,x_i\rangle|^2\|x_i\|^2+\left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,x_i\rangle x_i\right\|^2=(\clubsuit)$$
Now, using the orthonormality of $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$, I have that $\|x_i\|=1, \space \forall i=1,...,n$ and therefore  $$(\clubsuit)= \sum_{i=1}^n|\langle x,x_i\rangle|^2+\left\|x-\sum_{i=1}^n\langle x,x_i\rangle x_i\right\|^2$$
$\Box$
Is this correct? If it is, can be written better?

Are you familiar with projections?

Yes, I'm familiar with projections. Anyway, is my proof correct or is there something wrong? My teacher left this as an exercise....
